# How can change the font size for the name on my CV?

Tags: fontsize

I am currently writing a CV using the template found at https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/data-science-tech-resume-template/zcdmpfxrzjhv, but am having trouble reformatting to change the size of the for my name.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please don't post links to Overleaf templates. I'd love to try to help you, but I don't want to sign up for an Overleaf account just to get access to the template. If the template has a github page or similar, please link to that.

Answer (score 1):

If the template is the same as the one [here](https://github.com/TimmyChan/data-science-tech-resume-template), then the font size of the name is set by the command below which you'll find in the file `_header.tex`:

```
    \chead{%
        \centering {\Huge \skills \name \vspace{.25em}} \\ % feel free to adjust vspace to 0 
        {\color{highlight} \Large{\role}}}%
```

You can either change that directly, or you can reissue the same command with different parameters *after* `\input{_header}` but before `\begin{document}` inside the main document.

You'll just want to change "`\Huge`" to something else, e.g., `\LARGE` or `\Large` to make it a bit smaller, or `\HUGE` to make it even bigger.

```
    \chead{%
        \centering {\LARGE \skills \name \vspace{.25em}} \\
        {\color{highlight} \Large{\role}}}%
```

You can set the font size directly if you use `\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont` or similar in place of `\Huge`, but it's generally preferable to use one of the font size commands like `\LARGE` or `\HUGE`.

(The `TLCresume.sty` file loads the `moresize` package which defines `\HUGE` as bigger than `\Huge`. Otherwise the size options are those listed [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/latex-fonts-size-and-styles).)